# 'main' function not found in module when using llvm bindings with Haskell

Tags: haskell, llvm

I'm trying to use Haskell's LLVM bindings to create a very simple 'hello world' standalone app. The idea is, when I run my Haskell application, it will spit out some bytecode that can in turn be run and will output "hello world!"

```
-- hellofunc prints out "hello world"
hellofunc :: CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))


_main :: (Function (IO ())) -> CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
_main func = createNamedFunction ExternalLinkage "main" $ do
        call func
        ret ()

main = writeCodeGenModule "hello.bc" (liftA _main hellofunc)
```

When I run this, I see the following error:

```
'main' function not found in module.
```

I'm explicitly creating the `main` function using `createNamedFunction`. What am I missing?

Comment: You can try to `llvm-dis hello.bc` to see what's wrong with `@main`.

Comment: It gets written as _fun2. I'm trying to understand if I'm using `createNamedFunction` incorrectly or there is a bug in that function.

Comment: Btw. identifiers starting with an underscore like "_main" mark unused identifiers. GHC will not warn if they are not used. Thus, better only mark functions as unused if they are actually unused. See also: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4959

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the use of `liftA` or `fmap` rather than `=<<`. It becomes more obvious (a build break) when type signatures are used. _main is not evaluated in CodeGenModule in the liftA case, and so it doesn't appear in the output file.

It may be reasonable to modify `writeCodeGenModule` to take `CodeGenModule ()` instead of `CodeGenModule a`. It makes life just a bit more complicated for users of the LLVM JIT but would help prevent errors such as this one.

```
import Control.Applicative
import LLVM.Core
import LLVM.ExecutionEngine
import LLVM.Util.File

--
-- hellofunc prints out "hello world"
hellofunc :: CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
hellofunc = createNamedFunction ExternalLinkage "hello" $ do
  ret ()

_main :: (Function (IO ())) -> CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
_main func = createNamedFunction ExternalLinkage "main" $ do
  call func
  ret ()

generateModuleBind :: CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
generateModuleBind = _main =<< hellofunc

-- Couldn't match expected type `Function (IO ())'
--             with actual type `CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))'
--
-- this is the desired type:
-- generateModuleLiftA :: CodeGenModule (Function (IO ()))
--
-- but this is the actual type:
generateModuleLiftA :: CodeGenModule (CodeGenModule (Function (IO ())))
generateModuleLiftA = liftA _main hellofunc

main :: IO ()
main = writeCodeGenModule "hello.bc" generateModuleBind
```

Comment: Argh, thank you. The tl;dr for others looking for the answer: I used `CodeGenModule` as an Applicative instead of a Monad. I replaced `liftA` with an infix `=<<` and now everything works fine.