# Main Function not Found in the Bitcode file generated by compiling haskell with LLVM

Tags: haskell, llvm, ghc, llvm-ir, klee

I want to run klee on the .bc file generated by compiling haskell file with ghc frontend and llvm backend.

I have following code in my haskell hello.hs file:

```
main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

I compile hello.hs with ghc using following command

```
ghc -fllvm -keep-llvm-files -force-recomp -hello.hs
```

which generate a hello.ll file along with other files. I then try to compile this .ll file into a .bc file.

```
llvm-as hello.ll -o hello.bc
```

The problem is when I try to run klee or try to run lli on the the .bc file I get following error

```
main function not found in module error
```

I am running ghc and llvm on docker. I have version 3.4 of llvm and version 7.6.3 of ghc.

Comment: Like many modern languages, definitions in the language do not translate to identical declarations in bitcode or object files.  Read the .ll and see.

Comment: try adding `module Main where` as the first line of your Haskell file.

Comment: @ja Adding module Main did not work

Comment: Most likely Haskell links the `main` function into your program when you run it normally. Find a way to either link it in manually or find a way to create your own custom main function. See also: similar problems people had with Rust: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45860092/598057.

Comment: Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427535/main-function-not-found-in-module-when-using-llvm-bindings-with-haskell?rq=1

Comment: `ghc` complains `unrecognised flag: -force-recomp`.  It should be replaced by `-fforce-recomp`.